# IF in Sentence SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to help me with a sentence, I have the next table

```
publications
------------
id_publication,
publication,
flag,
id_user_dest,
id_user_source
```

It is an application of publications, where you can publish to other users, and also when publishing is a choice if you want a publication private (for that is the flag) and just look at it the user source and destination user, but not as make that sentence.

I have a table users where are the data users, and management 
sessions, in table PUBLICATIONS look who made the source publication and destination publication.

For example, if I am in the profile "Juan"

I program that spew me all publications that have been for $id_user_profile which is equal to Juan him out by GET

```
SELECT * FROM publications 
WHERE id_user_dest= '$id_user_profile' AND flag=0;
```

(Flag: 0 is public, and 1 is private)

In this sentence  I would throw all publications of the user profile, less private, and lack... if the SESSION that time equals id_user_dest or id_user_source, then if you show me the publication Flag 0.

How would the sentence if I want all publications appear only the flag=0 (public), but if flag=1 and the session equals id_user_source or id_user_dest, then the publication also appears  ?

thanks for read :)

Comment: I could not follow the question. Could you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for my english :)
The question is:
How would the sentence if I want all publications appear
only the flag=0 (public), but if flag=1 and the session equals  id_user_source or id_user_dest, then the publication also appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `or` logical operator is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   publications 
WHERE  flag = 0 OR '$id_user_profile' IN (id_user_dest, id_user_source)
```

EDIT:
As Michael Berkowski noted, this query assumes that `flag` can only be `0` or `1`. If this assumption is incorrect, the query should treat `flag=1` explicitly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   publications 
WHERE  flag = 0 OR 
       (flag = 1 AND '$id_user_profile' IN (id_user_dest, id_user_source))
```

Comment: And if there are more than just `0,1` possible for `flag` then `flag=0 OR (flag=1 AND '$id_user_profile' IN (id_user_dest, id_user_source))`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The OP seems to suggest that `flag` can either be `0` or `1`, but you are right. I added this comment to my answer. Thanks!